# mvc3 calling PartialViews inside ActionResult to put inside DIVs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, renderpartial

Quick Recap:I have a car website and I have a simple **ActionResult** with authorization each user that has access to that Controller will have 1 Make of car either a BMW,Honda,Ford or Kia, so that as soon as they login they see the make of car's automatically. I already have the PartialView set but my question is how can I from the ActionResult call the PartialView and fit it inside a DIV within the View?

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Mycars()
    {

// How can I return a PartialView here and put it inside a DIV like
// the partialview is called "Mymakes" and its a PartialViewResult
// I just can't seem to put it inside a DIV from here
        return View();

    }
```

As said the **PartialViewResult** works perfectly I have tested it using Ajax.BeginForm
now just trying to render it automatically in the ActionResult any tips would be great !!

Comment: Hmmm, not sure to understand... A partialView is called from a View  : `@Html.Partial(...)`, not from  the controller.

Comment: can a controller action be called from @Html.Partial(...) , as the PartialViewResult has to make a call to the Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main view (`Mycars`), use [@Html.Action()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee703423%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

you will create the corresponding Action in your controller (you can set the attribute `[ChildActionOnly]`, and it can be of type `PartialViewResult`

You will then create the (partial) `View` corresponding to that `PartialViewResult`, and... that's it.